# How to create isset($_POST['id'.$var]) within loops?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a page where there are several fields and users can comment on each one. To create these fields and text inputs, I am running a while loop with the following html within it:

```
<form name = "replyform" method = "post" action = "">           
<input id = "replytext<? echo $replyID; ?>" value = "replytext<? echo $replyID; ?>" name     = "replytext<? echo $replyID; ?>" type="text" class = "span5">
</form>
```

And then using the following code to call the 'wall_reply()' function, submitting the text values.

```
if (isset($_POST['replytext'.$replyID])) {
echo wall_reply();//5, $_POST['replytext'.$replyID]);
}
```

Something's a miss though. Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Comment: Sorry, when I say "something's a miss", I should have elaborated. The function wall_reply() just does a simply mySQL query. It doesn't look like the query is even being called which is questioning how I have constructed the id's and $_POST['replytext'.$var].

Comment: is `$replyID` being set before your `if` statement?

Comment: Hi Sam, yes it is. When I inspect the div id's in the browser, they're all being passed in ok.

Comment: are you running the loop on the form or on the input, it's not indicated in your code

Answer (score 0):

You have loop to create these form and input?

put the loop inside the form tag, so that only one form will be created with multiple inputs.

Answer (score 0):

this seem to work correctly, use it as your guide ;)

```
<?php 
$maxposts=7;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

function wall_reply($id,$text){
echo '<hr />updating id '.$id.' with '.$text;
}

var_dump($_POST);
for ($i=0;$i<$maxposts;$i++){
$replyID = $i;
        if (isset($_POST['replytext'.$replyID])) {
                 wall_reply($i,$_POST['replytext'.$replyID]);//5, $_POST['replytext'.$replyID]);
        } else {
                echo 'not set';
        }
}
}

?>
<form name = "replyform" method = "post" action = "">           
<?php 
$replyID = 5;
for ($i=0;$i<$maxposts;$i++):
$replyID = $i;
?>
<input id = "replytext<?php echo $replyID; ?>" value = "replytext<?php echo $replyID; ?>" name     = "$
<?php endfor; ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="go"/>
</form>
```